# A question about a part of a proof of Picard's little theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, entire-functions

Picard's little theorem states that if $f$ is a non-constant entire function, then $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(\mathbb{C})$ contains at most one point.

Now in the proof we assume that $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}\setminus f(\mathbb{C})$ and we define two harmonic functions $h:=\log|f-\alpha|$ and $k:=\log|f-\beta|$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Why does it then follow that $$|h^{+}-k^+|\leq |\alpha-\beta|$$ and $$\max(h,k)\geq \log(|\alpha-\beta|/2)$$

Comment: I edited some of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bullet$ If $| f - \alpha|, | f - \beta|$ are both $\leq 1$, then $h^+ - k^+ = 0$, then the first inequality is trivial.

$\bullet$ If $| f - \alpha|\leq 1$, and  $| f - \beta| > 1$, then 
$$
\vert h^+ - k^+ \vert = \log \vert f - \beta \vert = \log \vert f -\alpha + \alpha- \beta \vert \leq  \log\big( \vert f -\alpha \vert + \vert \alpha- \beta \vert \big) \leq \log\big( 1 + \vert \alpha- \beta \vert  \big)
$$
which is $\leq \vert \alpha- \beta \vert$.

$\bullet$ If $| f - \alpha| \geq | f - \beta|\geq 1$, then 
$$
\vert h^+ - k^+ \vert =  \log  \vert\frac{ f - \alpha }{ f - \beta}\vert = \log\Big( \vert 1 + \frac{\beta- \alpha}{f -\beta} \vert \Big)\leq \log\Big( 1 + \vert \alpha - \beta\vert \Big) \leq \vert \alpha- \beta \vert
$$

This gives us the first inequality.

the second inequality is equivalent to 
$$\max \Big\{ \vert f - \alpha\vert,  \vert f - \beta\vert \Big\} \geq  \frac{\vert \alpha - \beta\vert }{2} $$
while it follows from the basic triangle-inequality that
$$2\max \Big\{ \vert f - \alpha\vert,  \vert f - \beta\vert \Big\}\geq  \vert f - \alpha\vert +  \vert f - \beta\vert \geq \vert \alpha - \beta\vert \,.
$$
The proof is finished now.

Comment: I think I'm abit confused. $h^+$ denotes the points of $\mathbb{C}$ where $h$ is positive right?

Comment: @seht111, $h^+ :=\max\{ h, 0\}$. Note $h$ is real-valued function: $f -\beta \neq 0$, $\log \vert f - \beta\vert$ is the real part of the analytic function $\log (f - \beta)$ so the real-valued function $h$ is harmonic automatically.